# Exception: The parameters (String,DriveApp.File) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.makeCopy

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, methods, parameters, google-drive-api

I'm new to Script and was wondering if I could get help with a question. I'm currently trying to auto-fill a Google Doc from a Google Form submission. I've had success with a small test in the past, but since trying it a second time with a bit of a larger form, I'm encountering this error:

> "Exception: The parameters (String,DriveApp.File) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.makeCopy"

It isn't immediately clear to me what this is telling me. What I do know is that I'm not doing anything differently than my last small scale test so the script I'm running looks on the surface to be solid, so I'm hoping someone could help me out with pointing out what's wrong. Here's the script:

```
function autoFillFormFromDoc(e) {

  var clientCode = e.values[1];

  var email = e.values[2];

  var warningSigns = e.values[3];

  var internalCopingStrategies = e.values[4];

  var peopleAndSocial = e.values[5];

  var peopleWhoCare = e.values[6];

  var creatingSafety = e.values[7];

  var clientName = e.values[8];

  var date = e.values[9];
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1Vs8y3eZbyBlef8HlV7v9nhSRvaH39Cg5P0Q5zhpZBA");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFileById("1OxsOwU6rAvohqRqDVOfH_f70kvu30HZp");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(clientName, templateResponseFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{{ClientCode}}", clientCode);
  
  body.replaceText("{{Email}}", email);

  body.replaceText("{{WarningSigns}}", warningSigns);

  body.replaceText("{{InternalCopingStrategies}}", internalCopingStrategies);

  body.replaceText("{{PeopleAndSocial}}", peopleAndSocial);

  body.replaceText("{{PeopleWhoCare}}", peopleWhoCare);

  body.replaceText("{{CreatingSafety}}", creatingSafety);

  body.replaceText("{{ClientName}}", clientName);

  body.replaceText("{{Date}}", date);
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Issue:

[`File.makeCopy(name, destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination) expects  two  arguments

- `name` of type `string` and
- `destination` of type `folder`

The script calls `destination` with type `file`. Therefore it errors out with

> The parameters (String,DriveApp.File) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.makeCopy

#### Solution:

Get `folder` instead of `file`:

```
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("[FOLDER_ID]");
```